# How to declare variable/method type referred from the return type of another method

Tags: scala, metaprogramming

One of my method returns a Class type. I wanna use this Class type as the parameter/return type of another method like:

```
class A {
  def aClass: Class[_] = {
    if (...){
      classOf[String]
    }else{
      classOf[Int]
    }
  }
   //Neither works
  def kClass : aClass = {
    //...
  }
  def kClass : Class[aClass] = {
    //...
  }
}
```

It complains `Cannot resolve symbol aClass`.

Can this type of metaprogramming be achieved in Scala at all?

Comment: No, making a compile-time return type dependent on the run-time outcome of an `if-else` is not possible. Looks like an XY-problem. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Right

Comment: I still think that it *could* be an XY-problem, and you still didn't describe the original problem. In Scala, you can go quite far with path-dependent types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a type like this and can use that type. right now you are putting a def as a type and there is no type like aClass defined so it's giving you compile time error that aClass can't be resolved. I think that should work for you.

```
final type aClass = Class[_]

      class A {
        def aClass: Class[_] = {
          if (true){
            classOf[String]
          }else{
            classOf[Int]
          }
        }

        //should works
        def kClass: aClass = {
          ...
        }
        def kClass1: aClass = {
          ...
        }
      }
```

Comment: I'm somewhat mystified about the usefulness of the `_ >: String with Int` type. What is it good for in the above context?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question, so i can understand what exactly you are asking?

Comment: as far as i understand the problem, he wants the return type to be either class of string or class of Int on run time and that return type he wants from some other method so why the use of _ >: String with Int is mysterious ? what's wrong with that?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Since I don't understand what the OP is asking, I don't know what exactly you are answering... Using a method invocation in a position where a type is expected simply doesn't make any sense whatsoever in a non-dependently typed language. The fact that you introduce a type with a name that is confusingly the same as the name of the method `aClass` makes it only more confusing...

Comment: without invoking a method which has the same return type how we can be sure about the type of the method? i mean that's why i think he want to do some operation and at the last he will either call the method aClass or return something of the same type? what do you think he is trying to do?

Comment: Not really what I am looking for, but this task seems impossible in Scala as statically typed langugae

Comment: @texasbruce can you explain the problem in detail?